# how to set spacing between rows in my table

Tags: tables, spacing, multirow

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}} 
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Empresa ``i"}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Variable}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Modalidad}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Dirigido  a}} \\
          &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{18}[36]{*}{\textbf{E_i}} & \multirow{6}[12]{*}{Líneas en servicio} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Postpago} & Comercial \\
\cmidrule{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cmidrule{3-4}          &       & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Control} & Comercial \\
\cmidrule{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cmidrule{3-4}          &       & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Prepago} & Comercial \\
\cmidrule{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cmidrule{2-4}          & \multirow{6}[12]{*}{Tráfico Facturado} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Postpago} & Comercial \\
\cmidrule{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cmidrule{3-4}          &       & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Control} & Comercial \\
\cmidrule{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cmidrule{3-4}          &       & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Prepago} & Comercial \\
\cmidrule{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cmidrule{2-4}          & \multirow{6}[12]{*}{Ingresos} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Postpago} & Comercial \\
\cmidrule{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cmidrule{3-4}          &       & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Control} & Comercial \\
\cmidrule{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cmidrule{3-4}          &       & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Prepago} & Comercial \\
\cmidrule{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

this is my code, I really want to fix table up  to one that looks without spaces between rows. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic prescription when using the `booktabs` package is: "omit all vertical lines." They're not needed. Really.

Applying this rule to the present table, you should replace

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
```

with

```
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
```

Comment: or not to use `booktabs` rules and stick with `\hline` ...

Comment: @Zarko ... and `\cline`...

Comment: @Mico: I've provided a counter-example to the rule…

Comment: @Bernard - At least the vertical rules aren't connected all the way through from top to bottom...

Comment: @Mico: Which avoids to add horizontal rules as separators between groups, and is clearer than a couple of `\addlinespace`s, from my point of view. But as always, exceptions to the general law ‘No vertical rules’ depend on the case in point.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

I got above image after removing all `booktabs` rules and replace them with `\hline` and `\cline` and also remove unnecessary moving `multrow` cells. Also I employ `makecell` macro `thead` for setting column heads. More space between rows in table is obtained with change `\arraystretch` from default `1` to `1.5`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
    \hline
\thead{Empresa ``i"} & \thead{Variable}  &  \thead{Modalidad} & \thead{Dirigido  a} \\
    \hline
\multirow{18}{*}{\textbf{E\_i}} & \multirow{6}{*}{Líneas en servicio} & \multirow{2}{*}{Postpago} & Comercial \\
\cline{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cline{3-4}          &       & \multirow{2}{*}{Control} & Comercial \\
\cline{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cline{3-4}          &       & \multirow{2}{*}{Prepago} & Comercial \\
\cline{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cline{2-4}          & \multirow{6}{*}{Tráfico Facturado} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Postpago} & Comercial \\
\cline{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cline{3-4}          &       & \multirow{2}{*}{Control} & Comercial \\
\cline{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cline{3-4}          &       & \multirow{2}{*}{Prepago} & Comercial \\
\cline{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cline{2-4}          & \multirow{6}{*}{Ingresos} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Postpago} & Comercial \\
\cline{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cline{3-4}          &       & \multirow{2}{*}{Control} & Comercial \\
\cline{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
\cline{3-4}          &       & \multirow{2}{*}{Prepago} & Comercial \\
\cline{4-4}          &       &       & Residencial \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll delete my comments, which are private, so to say.

Answer (score 1):

I propose two possible layouts: the first is a variant of @Zarlo's solution, with a simpler code (without any `\multirow`) and less horizontal lines. The second uses still less horizontal lines and some vertical lines.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern} %
\usepackage{graphicx,array,multirow, makecell, booktabs, caption}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\newcommand\ComRes{\ensuremath{\left[\begin{tabular}{l@{}}Comercial\\[-0.3ex]Residencial \end{tabular}\right.}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering \caption{Add caption} %
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
\toprule%multirow{2}[2]{*}
 \thead{Empresa “i”} & \thead{Variable} & \thead{Modalidad} & \thead{Dirigido a} \\%
 \midrule %
 & & Postpago & \makecell{Comercial \\ Residencial}\\%
\cmidrule{3-4}%
 & Líneas en servicio & Control & \makecell{Comercial \\ Residencial}\\%
\cmidrule{3-4}%
 & & Prepago &\makecell{ Comercial \\ Residencial }\\%
%%%%%%%%%
 \cmidrule{2-4}%
  & & Postpago & \makecell{Comercial \\ Residencial}\\%%
\cmidrule{3-4}%
\textbf{E\textsubscript{i}} & Tráfico Facturado & Control & \makecell{Comercial \\ Residencial}\\%
 \cmidrule{3-4}%
 & & Prepago &\makecell{ Comercial \\ Residencial }\\%
%%%%%%%%%
 \cmidrule{2-4}%
  & & Postpago & \makecell{Comercial \\ Residencial}\\%
 \cmidrule{3-4}%
  & Ingresos & Control & \makecell{Comercial \\ Residencial}\\%
 \cmidrule{3-4}%
 & & Prepago &\makecell{ Comercial \\ Residencial }\\%%
 \bottomrule%
 \end{tabular}%
 \label{tab1:addlabel}
 \end{table}%
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering \caption{Add caption} %
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{cr!{\vrule width 1.2pt}c c}
\toprule%multirow{2}[2]{*}
 \thead{Empresa “i”} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Variable}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Modalidad}} & \thead{Dirigido a} \\%
 \midrule
 \addlinespace %
 & & Postpago & \ComRes \\%
 & Líneas en servicio & Control & \ComRes \\%
 & & Prepago & \ComRes \\%
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
  & & Postpago & \ComRes \\%%
\textbf{E\textsubscript{i}} & Tráfico Facturado & Control & \ComRes \\%
 & & Prepago & \ComRes \\%
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
  & & Postpago & \ComRes \\%
  & Ingresos & Control & \ComRes \\%
 & & Prepago & \ComRes \\%
 \addlinespace
 \bottomrule%
 \end{tabular}%
 \label{tab2:addlabel}
 \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]